# Unable to view or export file in lyx, linux mint

Tags: lyx, document-classes, linux

I had this problem a week or two ago and I posted here but nothing from the suggested solutions seemed to work. I have managed to get some more details on it, in case anyone can help me, because this issue is causing me huge productivity problems and I really want it solved.

So I'm using Linux mint distribution, and I've installed Lyx via the software manager. Every time that I open a new document, I get an error claiming that some files are missing, and until they are installed, compiling the files or exporting them as pdfs is not possible. The file in question is called "extarticle.cls". Additionally, under Document->Settings->Document Class, every document class is marked as unavailable.

Here is the thing though.. this file is not missing... I have located it inside a folder associated with Lyx. It's *definitely not* missing.

I really need help with this one guys... It's been weeks since the problem came up and I really just want to be rid of it.. Why does this thing not work? Any help?

Comment: Did you installed texlive as mentioned in the comments of your previous question?

Comment: I did. In fact, I even tried uninstalling all packages I had, then installing them again. Nothing changed.

Comment: What was the command you gave to install texlive?

Comment: I installed it from the software manager. The package was named "texlive-all", with the description: "Tex live: metapackage pulling in all components of tex live". Was that a mistake? Should I have done it via the terminal?

Comment: I suppose it is ok... Let's try to build a pdf via pdflatex now... This will answer if the problem is Lyx-specific... Open gedit and copy paste the first example from here: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/LaTeX/helloworld.tex... then save it as `test.tex` and run the command (from the same folder): `pdflatex test.tex`.... See if a `test.pdf` created and if it looks ok.

Comment: Yup.. works fine. It made the .pdf and I can open it normally.

Comment: Nice... Next step is just from my experience... I installed lyx after texlive and may be lyx found texlive installed and used its libraries... So, uninstall lyx and insatall it again: `sudo apt remove --purge lyx` and after that `sudo apt install lyx`.

Comment: I just noticed in my home folder there is a .lyx directory... Please remove it before reinstalling if not removed by the command... We want a clean installation of lyx after removing it... Sorry if already tried...

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is still there. I even repeated your instructions after making sure there were no directories.

Comment: Can you just create a new file using lyx now? not open one ... but create a simple new...

Comment: I can open new files, and write in them. I can open math environments, insert graphics, and basically everything else. But when I'm done with everything, I can't export it as a .pdf file, and nor can I view it as one. What I can do, however, is view it as a LyxHTML file, though I get the feeling it completely ignores any format I've done. Edit: I can also save it as a .lyx file, and doing so gives me the error claiming I am missing files from my installation.

Comment: In my Lyx->Tools->preferences, I have file handling I have LaTeX (pdflatex) converter:`pdflatex $$i` and Extra flag: `latex=pdflatex`... Can you check if you have the same settings? and if so, try with `pdflatex -file-line-error $$i` in converter... (found here: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=8067) If it doesn't work again revert to default... (A reconfigure would be useful too from the tools menu)

Comment: Well I'll be damned... that was it!! It works now! Thank you so so much!!!

Comment: Do you want to tell me what exactly worked to make it an answer available for future users too? I mean that I need to know if the field there was empty and what you wrote there to make it work... (You are welcome)